# Numpy get index of row with second-largest value

Tags: python, numpy

I am aware of how to get the index of the row containing the largest element with this snippet:

```
np.argmax(np.max(x, axis=0))
```

However, how could I get the index of the second largest row?  I figure that I can cut off a row of x then try again, but is there a more elegant solution to this which can be scaled for the 3rd largest, 4th, etc?

Comment: What's `x`, a 2d array? Can you define precisely "largest row"? Can you provide a numeric example of desired input and output?

Comment: @jpp x is a 3x3 array, but it should work for any square array.  By largest row, I mean the row that contains the largest value.  For example, np.array([[0., 1., 0.],
              [1., 0., 5.],
              [6., 4., 2.]])  
has its row with the largest value at index 2.

Comment: shouldn't it be `np.argmax(np.max(x, axis=1))` for your example?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `np.argsort(np.max(x, axis=0))[-2]`.

This scales to any index you want by changing the slicing index from `-2` to `-index`.

Comment: To me it seems the `np.max` is not necessary and it is enough to write `np.argsort(x, axis=0)[-2]`

Comment: if your array is not 1D, then your proposal would not return a scalar, but a (N-1)D array.

Comment: This one method is faster than the using `row, col = np.unravel_index ...` . timeit status:
for a random arrays reads:

`x.shape = (6,100000)`: 6 ms vs. 55 ms, and 
`x.shape` = (100000,6): 1 ms vs. 50 ms

Answer (score 5):

Use `argsort` on flattened version and then use `np.unravel_index` to get row, col indices -

```
row,col = np.unravel_index(np.argsort(x.ravel()),x.shape)
```

Then, the largest row index would be `row[-1]`, second largest in `row[-2]` and so on. Similarly, for columns, use `col`.

So, for convenience, you can flip the elements and use :

```
row,col = row[::-1],col[::-1]
```

Then, the largest ones would be at `[0]`, second largest at `[1]` and so on.